# Visiting Abkhazia from Georgia 2023

Tags: georgia-country, disputed-territories, abkhazia

I travel on a passport from an EU country, and I would like to visit Abkhazia from Georgia in March this year. Is that still possible, and is it safe?

Comment: It seems there's one open border crossing (where you have to walk across the border). Source: https://againstthecompass.com/en/travel-abkhazia/#3 or https://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/georgia/#georgia-%e2%80%93-abkhazia-border-crossings Abkhazia itself is safe for tourists; no more dangerous than Georgia.